# Opening a product tab on click of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, shopify

I'm trying to get a particular tab on a webpage to open when a link is clicked. Not only that, I need the page to scroll down to that area once it's clicked too (like an anchor tag).

Here's the page I'm working on:

Code:

```
<a onclick="$('#ReviewsTabLink').click(); $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#ReviewsTabLink').offset().top + 'px'}, 'fast'); "> 
    <div class="product-review">
        <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code that you've written? What do you expect it to do, and what is actually happening? As much as possible, please try to keep your question self-contained, and focused solely on the issue you're having; the site that you're working on is likely irrelevant.

Comment: i want when click the review  so its scroll down and open review tab. https://www.pearlysfashion.co.uk/collections/fashion-jewellery/products/bridesmaid-bracelet#tab_review

Comment: <a href="ReviewsTabLink"></a> it will scroll to #ReviewsTabLink, if present in document

Comment: @KamalSharma Please re-read my comment. As is, your question does not describe any issues with the code that you've written.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz That (empty) anchor link would simply redirect you to a new page named ReviewsTabLink.

Comment: this is present in my doc   <a href="#tab_review">
          <div class="product-review">
          <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span>
          </div></a>

Comment: Sorry I miss the # in href

Comment: @KamalSharma Please include any relevant information as an *edit* to your question, rather than a comment.

Comment: @MayankPandeyz  please help how it solve

Comment: Please send your comment

Comment: Help this code:  
this is present in my doc <a href="#tab_review"> <div class="product-review"> <span class="shopify-product-reviews-badge" data-id="{{ product.id }}"></span> </div></a>